# Request goes to the wrong function in Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests

The following is the URL pattern specified in my code.

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^layout/$', views.layout, name='layout'),
]
```

I have three functions specified as

```
def detail(request,uuid) 
def index(request)
def layout(request):
```

However, whenever I type the 'layout' keyword, I get the following error:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in  inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Aditya Ranganath\PycharmProjects\untitled\untitled1\polls\views.py" in detail
  38.     path = Attribute[0]['Path']

Exception Type: IndexError at /polls/layout/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Which essentially means the request is sent to the wrong function. After debugging it, I have realized that the function goes into the detail function.

Kindly let me know why this is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: `layout/` fits the regular expression above as well. Make it more specific!

Comment: the label was layoutFacilities_A initially. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^layout/$', views.layout, name='layout'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

]

In other word, move layout before detail. Because regex on detail also can match to term `layout`

Comment: As I wrote above, if you type url like /layout/, it will match by regex, (?P<uuid>[\w\-]+) used in detail URL